# how to reload view objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone

How to reload the app after I click a button?
I have the button called reset, I want get rid of all the user input , such as erase all the text typed in textfield, initialize all variable. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: When the button is activated just do `_textField.text = @"";`, etc.

Comment: Because you need to reload the entire page? why only you can not give a `setText` to ""?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the view property in view controller to nil first, then try access it it would get recreated automatically:

```
 [controller setView:nil]; 
 [controller view]
```

This will reload the view immediately and trigger `viewDidLoad`

However, from performance perspective reloading the view is quite expensive, I would suggest you write a reset function to put the reset code of all the field you want to get rid of in it. And call that method when user clicks the button.